# Monitor file owner

Tags: file-management, resource-monitoring

There's a file (`stream.wav`) which appears from time to time on the `/sdcard` and it grows large and eventually eats up all available space. I need to find out the application which opens this file and keeps it growing.

Is there any way to determine this?

PS. The Android device is rooted.

Comment: Afraid this would be hard: sdcard uses a file system which doesn't support ownership. What you could try, however, is utilizing `adb shell` and run the `lsof` command, e.g. `adb shell "lsof | grep file.ext"` (if that file is named `file.ext`). This would show which process/app is accessing it. Then grep for that owner in `adb shell "ls -l /data/data | grep xxx"` (replace xxx by the owner retrieved via `lsof`). In both cases, run the command as root.

Comment: Great! Thanks for mentioning ``lsof``, almost forgot about it! FS ownership is useless to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rooted phones only, on the terminal (or after `adb shell`):

```
su 
lsof | grep -i stream.wav
```

The output will look like

```
sdcard     206   media_rw    7   ... /data/media/0/stream.wav
XXXXXXXXX  6226     u0_a94   27  ...  /storage/emulated/legacy/stream.wav
```

which shows `XXXXXXXXX` (masked) is responsible for the file.

Thanks to Izzy's comment, this is his answer, but a bit reformulated.