# Monitor and identify which apps create a specific file/directory

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, resource-monitoring

From time to time, there is a directory (and files inside of it) that is created on the internal memory of my device. I keep deleting it, but after a few days/weeks, it's back. The folder in question, by the way, is Tencent. I already uninstalled the game associated with them long ago, but the directory keeps popping up.

I would like to know what other app is creating it. I don't have that many apps, mainly social media ones and tools, and I think they are only associated with games.

Searching around, I found an app that logs all accesses to files of the filesystem, but it doesn't show what app is doing it.

The answer from [Software to monitor file owner](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/122440) is not going to work in my case because these files are all 0 bytes so it's way too fast to catch the app creating them. Not to mention that the creation time is random. It could take days or weeks for the app to create it again.

Anyone have some good ideas before going into detective mode as last resort? I'm firstly asking for an app because that would be the easiest way to monitor the filesystem.

PS: My device is rooted.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't post the exact and full path name of that folder? The community here often has some valuable hints which app may have created those files. Tracing the origin of file operations is not possible on an unrooted Android (and even on a rooted device the ways I can imagine requires some programming skills for an Xposed module or a Frida hook).

Comment: [How to identify the app/process which re-mounts partitions R/W, creates files and changes file permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214229/how-to-identify-the-app-process-which-re-mounts-partitions-r-w-creates-files-an)

Comment: @Robert, it's a folder named Tencent in the root of the internal memory.

Comment: I think a fast loop in a terminal checking lsof with a filter for the folder name, also checking what apps have just been started, all that in a loop in a shell script, may do the trick. I will try that.